# I am making a bot in nextcord and I need to figure out how to disable a view

Tags: python, nextcord

I am trying to make an economy bot and one of the games is RPS. I am trying to figure out how to disable a view after a button is pressed. My code:

```py
    import nextcord
    import random
    client=nextcord.Client(intents=nextcord.Intents.all())
    def checkwin(useroption):
        optionIndex=random.randint(1,3)
        option=""
        if optionIndex==1:
            option="Rock"
        elif optionIndex==2:
            option="Paper"
        elif optionIndex==3:
            option="Scissors"
    
    
        if option==useroption:
            return "Tie"
        elif option=="Rock" and useroption=="Paper":
            return "Loss"
        elif option=="Rock" and useroption=="Scissors":
            return "Win"
        elif option=="Paper" and useroption=="Rock":
            return "Win"
        elif option=="Paper" and useroption=="Scissors":
            return "Loss"
        elif option=="Scissors" and useroption=="Rock":
            return "Loss"
        elif option=="Scissors" and useroption=="Paper":
            return "Win"
    
    class RPSBTNS(nextcord.ui.View):
        @nextcord.ui.button(label="Rock", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.red, emoji="")
        async def rock(self, button:nextcord.ui.Button, interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
            victory=checkwin("Rock")
            if victory=="Win":
                await interaction.send("You lose.")
            elif victory=="Loss":
                await interaction.send("You Win!")
            else:
                await interaction.send("Tie.")
    
        @nextcord.ui.button(label="Paper", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
        async def Paper(self, button:nextcord.ui.Button, interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
            victory=checkwin("Paper")
            if victory=="Win":
                await interaction.send("You lose.")
            elif victory=="Loss":
                await interaction.send("You Win!")
            else:
                await interaction.send("Tie.")
    
        @nextcord.ui.button(label="Scissors", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="✂️")
        async def scissors(self, button:nextcord.ui.Button, interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
            victory=checkwin("Scissors")
            if victory=="Win":
                await interaction.send("You lose.")
            elif victory=="Loss":
                await interaction.send("You Win!")
            else:
                await interaction.send("Tie.")
    
    @client.slash_command(name="test")
    async def test(interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
        await interaction.send("Rock Paper Scissors and shoot!", view=RPSBTNS())
    
    client.run("token")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all the buttons, you can edit the message with `view=None`.

```
await interaction.edit(view=None)
```

To disable all buttons, you can iterate over the children, setting disabled to True, then editing the message with the updated view.

```
for child in self.children:
    child.disabled = True
await interaction.edit(view=self)
```

Comment: Hi, How where would I implement this into my code?

Comment: @Anthony inside the button callback within the view, but you can implement it in other places if you change the references to use the correct message and view object. In this case, interaction is the button interaction, you could also use message.edit if you have the message instance. `self` in this case is the View class it is in. If you did it outside, you'd need a field or variable holding the view.